# compiling gcc from source gcc-13, call to deleted constructor of 'rtl_ssa::access_array_builder'

Tags: gcc

On gcc branch releases/gcc-13

Make command got this error, I don't know much about the requirements and config correctness of the config for the gcc compile from source process, can you give me some advice?

```
../.././gcc/rtl-ssa/accesses.cc:1422:24: error: call to deleted constructor of 'rtl_ssa::access_array_builder'
  access_array_builder builder (watermark);
                       ^        ~~~~~~~~~
../.././gcc/obstack-utils.h:79:28: note: 'obstack_watermark' has been explicitly marked deleted here
  DISABLE_COPY_AND_ASSIGN (obstack_watermark); 
                           ^
../.././gcc/rtl-ssa/accesses.cc:1465:24: error: call to deleted constructor of 'rtl_ssa::access_array_builder'
  access_array_builder builder (watermark);
                       ^        ~~~~~~~~~
../.././gcc/obstack-utils.h:79:28: note: 'obstack_watermark' has been explicitly marked deleted here
  DISABLE_COPY_AND_ASSIGN (obstack_watermark); 
                           ^
../.././gcc/rtl-ssa/accesses.cc:1514:23: error: call to deleted constructor of 'rtl_ssa::access_array_builder'
        access_array_builder builder (watermark);
                             ^        ~~~~~~~~~
../.././gcc/obstack-utils.h:79:28: note: 'obstack_watermark' has been explicitly marked deleted here
  DISABLE_COPY_AND_ASSIGN (obstack_watermark); 
                           ^
7 warnings and 3 errors generated.
```

build toolset:

```
clang -version
clang version 4.0.0-1kord1 (tags/RELEASE_400/rc1)
Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

my config:

```
./configure \
--host=aarch64-linux-gnu \
--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go \
--prefix=/home/.gccb/gcc-13 \
--enable-targets=aarch64-linux-gnu \
--with-gmp=/usr/local \
--with-mpfr=/usr/local \
--with-mpc=/usr/local
```

Comment: configuring GCC in the source directory is not supported. Build in a SEPERATE build directory OUTSIDE the source tree. What's the build platform? Are you trying to build a cross compiler? clang v4 seems quite antique, current is around v17.

Comment: After I switched to releases/gcc-9 with the config above, it compiles.  But with only c,c++ language enabled. it's an ARM cpu pre  2020 by a none famous manufacture. It was not cross, just native compile.